# php mySQL Reliable way to check if a row matches a object class

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm looking for a reliable way to check to see if a database entry matches an equivalent object class in php.

My current method is unreliable, I was hoping someone could supply a better solution.

My current solution seems to work most of the time, but out of around 600 entries, Ill randomly return about 5 entry's that are false positives.

Here is a simplified object class Im using

```
 class MemberData
{
     public $AccountID;
     public $AccountName;
     public $Website;
}
```

I then use reflection to loop through  each property in the class and build my query string in the form of :

```
SELECT 1 WHERE `Property1` = value1 AND `Property2` = value2 AND `Property3` = value3
```

However like i mentioned, my code only works most of the time, and I cant pin down a common link on why Im getting false positives. It appears random.

Below is my full function.

```
//Pass in a member class and see if there is a matching database entry
function SqlDoRowValuesMatch($memberData)
{
    //declare global vars into this scope
    global $host, $user, $password, $dbname, $tableName;    

    //initiate the connection using mysqli
    $databaseConnection = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $dbname);

    if($databaseConnection->connect_errno > 0)
    {
        die('Unable to connect to database [' . $databaseConnection->connect_error . ']');
    }

    //Get all the properties in the MemberData Class
    //Using Reflection
    $reflect = new ReflectionClass($memberData);
    $props = $reflect->getProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC);

    //Build the query string
    $sql =  "SELECT 1 FROM `".$tableName."` WHERE ";

    foreach($props as $prop)
    {
        if(!is_null($prop->getValue($memberData)))
        {                       
            $sql = $sql.$prop->getName()."=".addSingleQuotes(addslashes($prop->getValue($memberData)))." AND ";                 
        }
    }

    //Cut Trailing operator
    $sql = rtrim($sql, " AND ");    

    if(!$result = $databaseConnection->query($sql))
    {
            die('There was an error creating [' . $databaseConnection->error . ']');
    }

    $databaseConnection->close();


    //Check for a value of 1 to indicate that a match was found
    $rowsMatch = 0;

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {       
        foreach($row as $key => $value)
            {
                if($value == 1)
                {
                    $rowsMatch = 1;
                    break;
                 }
            }
    }   

    return $rowsMatch;  //0 = false, 1 = true
}
```

Comment: Instead of `select 1`, use `select AccountID` and print this out in your `while` loop, so you can see which rows are causing the false positives.

Comment: Ive printed out all the data for the false positives from the object classes and from the database side by side, and the data seems to match the database exactly.

Comment: Then why is it a false positive if it matches?

Comment: Its reporting that they don't match...false negative?

Comment: `addslashes()` escapes _"single quote ('), double quote ("), backslash (\) and NUL (the NULL byte)."_, `mmysqli_real_escape_string()` escapes _"NUL (ASCII 0), \n, \r, \, ', ", and Control-Z"_ The - be it slight - difference in functionality suggests to me you might want to use the actual tool provided for escaping.

Comment: It didn't seem to solve my issue completely but it defiantly helped it. +1 for better practice.